# Read until an only partially known line - Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to get (parse) from a device its whole output.

My solution was: 1) Determine how the last line of its output looks like

2) Use the code below to read the output until the last line (which is a way around of saying - read the whole output)

```
last_line = "text of the last line"
read_until(last_line)
```

3) Technical detail: make it to a `return` value of the `get_output()` as means of passing it further to a `parse_result()` function.

The problem is: The last line might take various forms and only its rough format is known. For example it might say: `{"diag":"hdd_id", "status":"0"}`. However, both `"diag"` and `"status"` might take other values than `"hdd_id"` and `"0"`.

What can I do to make the "text of the last line" more universal so that the read_until() stops for every value of "diag" and "status"? (given that the output always includes words "diag" and "status")

What I tried: Using regular expressions. Defining `last_line = re('"status":"."}')` making use of the fact that `.` in regular expression means any value. What I get though is `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

It also wouldn't make much sense to convert that regular expression to a string by `str(re('"status":"."}'))` since, as far as I understand regular expressions, it wouldn't mean any particular string (due to `.`).

Comment: Can you post some code? Is `read_until` a library function or something you're writing yourself?

Comment: `read_until` is a library function of telnetlib.py - since the output of the device is being read through a TelNet connection. Here's the essential part of its definition:


`def read_until(self, match, timeout=None):
        """Read until a given string is encountered or until timeout.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read (again) the `re` chapter from the Python standard library manual.

The correct usage is:

```
import re
...
eof = re.compile(r'\s*\{\s*"diag":.*,\s*"status":.*\}') # compile the regex
...
```

The above expression uses `\s*` to allow for optional white spaces in the line. You can remove them if you know that they cannot occur.

You can then use it with the `telnetlib` Python module, but with `expect` instead of `read_until`, because the latter searches for a string and not a regex:

```
index, match, text = tn.expect([eof])
```

Here, index will the the index of the matched regex (here 0), match the match object, and text the full text including the last line

Comment: The problem here is the `line` part. I don't have any bunch of text, whose lines I could try matching with my pattern.

Comment: The first moment I will obtain a piece of text (able to be further parsed or stored as a variable, and thus matched) is when I already stop my `read_until` - and for that I need to define a universal stopping point.

Comment: See my edit: you were not using the correct telnetlib function.

Comment: Here's what I got after applying this:

  `File "C:\Python27\lib\telnetlib.py", line 593, in expect

    list = list[:]

TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
Not quite sure about the meaning of that.

Comment: @Bolo: the parameter of expect must be a list. I wrote `expect([eof])`. Didn't you write `expect(eof)`?

Comment: Thanks. The thing is currently 80% working, so the initial problem is pretty much solved. Do you however have an idea why my output starts with some strange `(0, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02967FA8>, '`, doesn't convert any `\n`s into new lines and ends with unexpected `')`? My guess is, it must have something to do with regexp not acting like common strings, but the format (even the "\n" issue) stays even after conversion with str(regexp): `result = str(conn.expect([last_line]))`